# Strange issue using Mod_rewrite and $_GET variable

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

After reading tons of SO questions, asking friends and so one, I'm coming here with a strange issue regarding Apache mod_rewrite.

I'm trying to catch `http://api.server.com/.../results.php?id=X` URL though a RewriteRule.

Quite simple you'll say, I know it, my `.htaccess` file content is :

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^results/(.*)$ results.php?id=$1
```

`results.php` is quite simple for debugging reasons, looks like

```php
    var_dump($_GET);
```

But this script always return `array 0 { }`

Shall I specify that I've already tried to clear the flags, and change the `(.*)` class by others, without effects.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Does appending the [QSA] flag to your rewrite rule change anything ? Also, what URL are you accessing the script through ?

Comment: what is the URL are you entering into your browser?

Comment: Are you trying to catch results.php or rewrite to results.php?

Comment: @T.Fabre [QSA] flag does nothing :/ already tried.

Comment: @cmorrissey Is it secure to give the full URL ? It's a classical http request (can send it to you by PM).

Comment: @Machavity I want to catch results.php which will return me a json feed

Comment: @BergzBoy send the part after the domain only ie if your URL http://example.com/results/123; only send /results/123. Or give a fake domain name.

Comment: @BergzBoy   just say i am hitting the following url with my browser it doesn't need to include the sensitive stuff `http://api.fakedomain.com/folder/folder/results.php` <- thats currently not what your writing your rule for you are writing it for `http://api.fakedomain.com/results/1`

Comment: Oh ! Sure `http://api.server.com/customer/2/results.php` here is the full path. I should mention that I put `.htaccess` file on /2/ folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to disable `MultiViews` option here:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^results/(.*)$ results.php?id=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Option `MultiViews` is used by `Apache's content negotiation module` that runs **before** `mod_rewrite` and makes Apache server match extensions of files. So `/file` can be in URL but it will serve `/file.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Your rewrite rule does not match the URL you are using (http://api.server.com/customer/2/results.php).

The correct URL according to your rule and setup is:

```
http://api.server.com/customer/2/results/123
```

However, you mention having placed everything in the /2/ folder. If 2 is the ID you are trying to get, it cannot work -- URL rewriting only works with non-existing paths.

Instead you should place your .htacess and results.php file in the customer folder, and use the following URL:

```
http://api.server.com/customer/results/2
```

Or change your rule and URL to:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/results$ results.php?id=$1
http://api.server.com/customer/2/results
```

Comment: Oh no ! Here /2/ is the second version of the API.